# Make single maven dependency local only

Tags: java, maven

I have many dependencies in my project, almost all of which can be fetched from a remote repository. However, one of the repositories used contains a dependency that I build a custom version of locally using provided tools for that (hence why I'm not just building it to a custom location, figuring that out is a last resort).

I would like to fetch all my dependencies from remote repositories, except for the one I am building locally. I cannot remove the repository that contains it, as it contains more of my dependencies that I **DO** want to update.

In addition, this is a project shared with others, so a system scope and a systemPath attribute aren't going to work.

I cannot run maven in offline mode, as I do want to update every other dependency regularly.

Thanks.

Comment: First make a change to the version or better to the artifactId of the project and deploy it to a local repository manager so you need no systemPatha dependency..

Comment: maven has the `<scope>provided</scope>` for this: https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html

Answer (score 0):

Let me start with one suggestion, do not try to override existing coordinates with your custom logic and hence the build. It will always add to the confusion and worst runtime exception will make it hard to debug the problem. You should

1. Change the coordinates of this custom build project - Best possible solution. This will be treated as any other dependency.
2. If you can't change the coordinates, change the version. Do add a [qualifier](http://books.sonatype.com/mvnref-book/reference/pom-relationships-sect-pom-syntax.html) to make it future proof for further release of this library from original source.
3. Always prefer to add this dependency in [dependency management section](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html). This will always give this library a preference over dependency mediation.
4. You could use [relocation mechanism](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Relocation) of distribution management. This will give a useful message to people. There always is a shared settings.xml across a company.